# If the users input contains a character in the randomized variable listWords

Tags: vb.net

```
    Sub WordGeneration()
    Dim listWords(4) As String
    listWords(0) = "juicy"
    listWords(1) = "aaron"
    listWords(2) = "power"
    listWords(3) = "weigh"
    listWords(4) = "public"
    'randomizes and picks a string from array to use
    Dim Rand As New Random()
    Dim Index As Integer = Rand.Next(0, listWords.Length - 1)

    Dim SelectedValue = listWords(Index)
```

The user would input a letter , and it will check if that letter is contained within the variable listWords , i think im overthinking this and theres a easy solution but i cannot for the life of me think how to implement this.

Comment: VBA i am using, Visual Studios.

Comment: Your answer to @ScottCraner 's question doesn't make sense. Perhaps you are unaware of the difference between VBA and VB.Net. You are using the latter.

Comment: I am fairly new so it seems i am unaware the difference.

Comment: VBA is a fairly old language. It is an interpreted language which runs *hosted* in another application (hence the A in VBA) such as Excel. As a language it is largely the same as VB6 which was replaced by VB.net in Visual Studios over a decade ago. VBA is still alive and kicking, especially in Excel. The languages are similar in many ways, but VBA isn't as object-oriented and doesn't have direct access to various .net runtime goodies. It also can't be used to make stand-alone executables.

Comment: Thank you for this , i now have a better understanding of this as if im honest i had no clue the difference , so it appears i am using vb.net as im coding in visual studio 2015.

Comment: In its infinite wisdom, Microsoft has created no fewer than 4 mutually incompatible languages with "Visual Basic" in their names (VB, VBA, VBScript, VB.net). On the positive side, there are a lot of similarities, and the learning curve is small in going from one to the other. On the negative side -- it can be confusing as heck and is occasionally the source of bugs (e.g. when a coder with experience in both tries to write a bit of VB.net code in a VBA project and wonders why it doesn't compile). Such bugs are usually easy enough to fix.

Comment: The code seems to have nothing to do with the title - picking a random item vs string contents in another string,  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: The code is related to the title , the code presented is the array and the randomized variable listWords. I am looking for a way to code it so the user inputs a letter and it checks if a character in the users input , is present in the variable listWords.

Comment: a) it needs to be a function returning the pick; `SelectedValue` will only exist in that method b) use one Random for the entire app c) no idea where the user pick comes from, make it a parameter maybe d) `Dim qualified = listWords.Where(Function(q) q.StartsWith(pick)).ToArray()` will give you the sub list of eligible words, plick a random one (of there are any)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an odd request.
Given a button on a windows form, code to do what you want is below.
Just replace the "a" with your actual input.

Consider breaking apart the random word generation and the actual test for the character into two separate pieces.

Good luck

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim randomWord As String = GetRandomWord()
        Dim userInput As Char = "a"
        If randomWord.Contains(userInput) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Yes, the word '" + randomWord + "' DOES contain the letter '" + userInput + "'")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("No, the word '" + randomWord + "' DOES NOT contain the letter '" + userInput + "'")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function GetRandomWord() As String
        Dim listWords(4) As String
        listWords(0) = "juicy"
        listWords(1) = "aaron"
        listWords(2) = "power"
        listWords(3) = "weigh"
        listWords(4) = "public"
        Dim Index As Integer = GetRandomNumber(listWords.Length - 1)
        Return listWords(Index)
    End Function

    Private Function GetRandomNumber(maxValue As Integer) As Integer
        'Math.Ceiling rounds up to the nearest whole number
        Return Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * maxValue)
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: wouldn't that random never pick the word public? 0 to (5-1 which is 4) exclusive so 3?

Comment: Yes i have noticed that , how would i fix that?

Comment: I have updated the answer with the answer to your question, which I found a concise solution to at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41941280/if-the-users-input-contains-a-character-in-the-randomized-variable-listwords/41942140#41942140